# Update Trigger in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am new to SQL Server

I have to create a trigger for update

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_update
ON [GP].[dbo].[TABLE1]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 

DECLARE @PKCOL1 int 
DECLARE @COL2 int
DECLARE @COL3 nvarchar(36) 
DECLARE @COL4 nvarchar(36)
DECLARE @COL5 nvarchar(126) 
DECLARE @COL6 datetime 
DECLARE @COL7 datetime

BEGIN
SELECT     @PKCOL1     = [COL-A],
       @COL2       = [COL-B],
       @COl3       =  NULL, 
       @COL4       = [COL-C],       
       @COL5       = [COL-D],
       @COL6       = [COL-E]    

FROM INSERTED 

   UPDATE [dbo].[TABLE2] 
   SET [COL2]            =  @COL2,
       [COL3]            =  @COL3,
       [COL4]            =   @COL4,
       [COL5]            =   @COL5


   WHERE COL2 = @PKCOL1
```

I am getting syntax error for where contition.

> Incorrect syntax near @PKCOL1 .

Can oany help me please...

Comment: Looks like you need and `END` to close the `BEGIN` prior to the select statement. No SQL Server handy, so I can't test. Also, SQL Server triggers fire once per statement, not once per row. Your will break if the update on [GP].[dbo].[TABLE1] is of more than one row. Instead of selecting one row's worth from inserted, use a single an update of dbo.table2 that reads from inserted and processes all the rows. Something like:  `update trgt, set .... from dbo.table2 trgt inner join inserted I on trgt.col2 = I.[COL-A]`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the answer is probably because you have a BEGIN without a matching END statement.

Secondly, and this is much more important - your trigger is assuming that only a single row will ever be updated at a time. Triggers only fire once per operation, and can update many rows (i.e., the INSERTED table has multiple rows). In your code, you're only retrieving a single row from INSERTED and updating TABLE2 with the values from this row. You would be better off doing something like:

```
UPDATE Table2 SET 
    [Col2] = i.[Col-B]
  , [Col3] = NULL
  , [Col4] = i.[Col-C]
  , [Col5] = i.[Col-D]
FROM Table2
JOIN INSERTED i ON Table2.Col2 = i.[Col-A]
```

(Untested code warning)

Comment: I think you need to have `Table2` in a `FROM` clause also for this form to work.

Comment: @Damien you're absolutely right - thanks. I'll fix it up. That's what I get for writing pseudo-code before I've had my morning coffee :)